# SwiftUI - Binding in ObservableObject

Tags: swiftui, binding, combine

Let's say we have a parent view like:

```
struct ParentView: View {
    @State var text: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        ChildView(text: $text)
    }
}
```

Child view like:

```
struct ChildView: View {

    @ObservedObject var childViewModel: ChildViewModel

    init(text: Binding<String>) {
        self.childViewModel = ChildViewModel(text: text)
    }

    var body: some View {
        ...
    }
}
```

And a view model for the child view:

```
class ChildViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var value = false
    @Binding var text: String

    init(text: Binding<String>) {
        self._text = text
    }

    ...
}
```

Making changes on the String binding inside the child's view model makes the ChildView re-draw causing the viewModel to recreate itself and hence reset the @Published parameter to its default value. What is the best way to handle this in your opinion?

Cheers!

Comment: Use `@StateObject`, not `@ObservableObject`. Also, you *may* want to reconsider whether you truly need a view model -- that is a topic often debated here.

Comment: I've tried using StateObject but then the binding's value in the viewModel doesn't seem to update when changed

Comment: How are you checking to see if it's updated? the `@Binding` property wrapper only works in Views out-of-the-box

Comment: Debugging it. I’m changing the binding from the childview

Comment: It would help if you showed how you're "watching" `text` in the ObservableObject or the ChildView. Right now, your code omits all of that.

Comment: `@Binding` only works in a SwiftUI `View` it will not work in a `class`, you can sometimes get the initial value but it depends on a `body` to get updated values.

Comment: I have  "if viewModel.text.isEmpty" inside the ChildView. How would I bind a property from the ParentView to the child's view model without binding?

Comment: `@Binding` is by definition a two way connection, `isEmpty` is a `get - only`

Comment: As mentioned above, you don't need the view model for that -- just keep the binding in your View and it'll update

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to use a custom struct as a single source of truth, and pass a binding into child views, e.g.

```
struct ChildViewConfig {
    var value = false
    var text: String = ""

    // mutating funcs for logic
    
    mutating func reset() {
        text = ""
    }
}

struct ParentView: View {
    @State var config = ChildViewConfig()

    var body: some View {
        ChildView(config: $config)
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {

    @Binding var config: ChildViewConfig

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Text", text: $config.text)
        ...
        Button("Reset") {
            config.reset()
        }
    }
}
```

"`ViewConfig` can maintain invariants on its properties and be tested independently. And because `ViewConfig` is a value type, any change to a property of `ViewConfig`, like its text, is visible as a change to `ViewConfig` itself." [[Data Essentials in SwiftUI WWDC 2020](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020-10040/?time=258)].